# how do I adjust conditional statements in p5.js

Tags: javascript, if-statement, p5.js

how do I write this in p5.js?

// - When snakeVenom dips below 0.29, nerve_gas dips below 0.59, and also lead goes above 0.56, reduce insulin by 0.01

Comment: `insulin -= (snakeVenom < 0.29 && nerve_gas < 0.59 && 0.56 < lead) ? 0 : 0.01;`

Comment: There's nothing specific to p5.js about this. This is just basic javascript. StackOverflow is not intended for questions that can be answered with very basic research. See: https://javascript.info/ifelse

Answer (score 0):

p5.js probs doesn't have anything easier for you, except if rather than using a while loop you could use function draw(){}

```
if(snakeVenom < 0.29 && nerve_gas < 0.59 && lead > 0.56) {
   insulin -= 0.01 // insulin = insulin - 0.01
}
```

And well, you could also do this with an object:

```
stuff = {
  snakeVenom: 1,
  nerve_gas: 1,
  lead: 1,
  insulin: 1
}

if(stuff.snak...){
  stuff.insulin -= 0.01
}
```

Unless this isn't exactly what you meant to ask.